# Decision tree regressor used less features as my input

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, mapper

So I defined a simple regression model as follows:

```
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn import tree

max_depth = 3
min_samples_leaf = 100

X = df[categorical]
y = df['target_value']

mapper = DataFrameMapper( 
      [(i,LabelBinarizer()) for i in categorical]
)

mapper.fit(X)
X_mapped = mapper.transform(X)

model = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=max_depth,min_samples_leaf=min_samples_leaf)
model.fit(X_mapped,y)
```

Now I want to extract the names of the learned features to make a meaningful visualization. I can extract the names of the features as shown below. This gives me a list of 223 features. However, the problem is that my model has only used 218 features (`model.n_features_` gives 218). This means 5 features have disappeared and now I there is no way for me to know which splits are being made in the decision tree, as it is uncertain which variables are not used by the model.

```
names = []

for feature in mapper.features:
    try:
        for feature_value in feature[1].classes_:
            names.append(feature[0]+'_'+feature_value)
    except:
        names.append(feature[0])
```

How is it possible the the tree is only trained on 218 features whilst I input 223? and how should I approach naming the features of my splits? Without running the risk of giving false conclusions (i.e. claiming a features is important whilst it is named wrongly)

edit: I found that the mapper transforms the X data into 218 features, but gives me a list of 223 names. So the 'problem' lies with the mapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the LabelBinarizer, which is de mapper in this case, encounters a categorical value with 2 unique values, it captures it in one column (0 and 1 both representing a class of the column). This results in 1 column with two feature names.
I solved this issues by editing the name gathering function to:

```
names = []

for feature in model['mapper'].features:
    try:
        if len(feature[1].classes_) == 2:
            names.append(feature[0]+'_'+feature[1].classes_[1])
        else:
            for feature_value in feature[1].classes_:
                names.append(feature[0]+'_'+feature_value)
    except:
        names.append(feature[0])
```